# Demystify Option ROM

Tags: firmware, option-rom

I know that option ROM is firmware code on adapter controller which gets initiated at system power-on. My question is, does that firmware code run locally on the adapter controller or on the system CPU? does that code ever need to be in the system memory?

Comment: It would help if you added some details like: Which adapter? What system?

Comment: Let's just say, a network card or a SATA card